# Maintain my component's properties when they are changed?

Tags: delphi, properties, components, delphi-7

I have a custom component with some published properties which have been used for a while in many projects. I want to make some particular changes to this component which requires removing these old properties and replacing them with new ones. Or otherwise, I'm not necessarily removing the properties, but let's say I just simply change the name of a property from `PropName` to `MyPropName` instead. Well, the next time any project using that component is opened, it will not be able to find `PropName`.

Is there any way to automate conversion of this? Or is this something people will have to do manually? What would be the proper way to maintain component property values when the names of those properties are changed?

And I mean just in the DFM code, not necessarily inside the source code.

Comment: Somebody is on a mad downvoting spree...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`DefineProperties`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.DefineProperties) extension point to help migrate your .dfm files.

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(...)
  private
    procedure ReadPropName(Reader: TReader);
  protected
    procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
  published
    property MyPropName: string read ... write ...;
  end;

procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('PropName', ReadPropName, nil, False);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.ReadPropName(Reader: TReader);
begin
  MyPropName := Reader.ReadString;
end;
```

This will allow your new component to read in old .dfm files with the old property name. When the .dfm file is written again, the new property name will be used.

Note that such a technique results in the component being able to read .dfm files containing either the old property name or the new property name so you can migrate in a gradual fashion if you wish. Once you have migrated all your .dfm files then it would be worth removing such code for the sake of tidiness.

The Delphi documentation covers this subject area, albeit from a slightly different perspective, in the [Storing and Loading Unpublished Properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Storing_and_Loading_Unpublished_Properties) section of the [Component Writer's Guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Component_Writer%27s_Guide_Index).

Comment: @David, I think you switched PropName and MyPropName in your answer, as the OP wants to replace old PropName property with new MyPropName property. Anyway, excellent answer, as it also helped me to tackle a problem I might get in the future.